# Что значит слово "ответственность" в контексте "ответственность за организацию мероприятия", "ответственность за безопасность"?

Tags: значение-слов

Что значит слово "ответственность"?
В контексте "ответственность за организацию мероприятия", "ответственность за безопасность" и т.п.

В словаре Ушакова приводится такое определение:

> Положение, при котором лицо, выполняющее какую-нибудь работу, обязано дать полный отчет в своих действиях и принять на себя вину за все могущие возникнуть последствия в исходе порученного дела, в выполнении каких-нибудь обязанностей, обязательств.

Что значит дать полный отчёт в своих действиях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кто-то берёт на себя ответственность за безопасность, то он:

- Обещает обеспечить эту безопасность.
- В случае неисполнения своего обещания готов нести на себе за это вину.

А "дать полный отчёт в своих действиях" - отчитаться (доложить, рассказать) кому-либо о том, что человек сделал (или не сделал), чтобы исполнить обещание.

Comment: Благодарю, друг!